# UdpClient only receives dgrams in one instance on same machine

Tags: c#, udp, udpclient

I am pretty new to socket programming and think, I didn't understand a crucial part.
I came across [this Microsoft example](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/framework/network-programming/using-udp-services). It shows an example of running a UDP server and client to listen to DGRAM packages. (I need to use UDP as I am trying to stream positions of players for a game.)

My problem occurs, when I start one server and two clients on the same machine: it is not possible to use the same port for two different instances of a UDPClient. I get this.
However, if I try different ports for each UDPClient, I would assume to be able to have two instances of UDPClients on one machine listening to the same server. 
However, it occurs that the second instance does not receive any UDP packages.

So my question is: How would I change the following code in order to be able to run two clients listening on broadcasting messages of one server on one machine?

Here is my server code:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

        IPAddress broadcast = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.255");

        byte[] sendbuf = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(args[0]);
        IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(broadcast, 11000);

        s.SendTo(sendbuf, ep);

        Console.WriteLine("Message sent to the broadcast address");
    }
}
```

And here is my client code:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

public class UDPListener
{
    private const int listenPort = 11000;

    private static void StartListener()
    {
        UdpClient listener = null;

        var tries = 0;
        while (listener == null){
            try
            {
                listener = new UdpClient(listenPort+tries);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                tries++;
                continue;
            }
        }

        IPEndPoint groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, listenPort);

        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for broadcast");
                byte[] bytes = listener.Receive(ref groupEP);

                Console.WriteLine($"Received broadcast from {groupEP} :");
                Console.WriteLine($" {Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)}");
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
        finally
        {
            listener.Close();
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        StartListener();
    }
}
```

Comment: To really learn UDP client/server, you should use simple examples, such as https://gist.github.com/darkguy2008/413a6fea3a5b4e67e5e0d96f750088a9 The Microsoft article focuses more on UDP broadcast, which is a completely different thing. Usually a UDP client sends broadcast packets to discover multiple servers (the same port but different IP addresses) in the same network. So you should try not to confuse yourself.

Comment: But if I understand correctly, you should use broadcasting to send streams of data or am I mistaken? If so, my application of sending position data of all players would be such a data stream. How would you approach this task of sending a data stream to multiple clients at once?